# Bad/illegal format or missing URL - Passing variable value inside custom curl

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl, ip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using a Linux shell (Ubuntu 20.04) in my Windows 10 Machine. I have a bash script that is supposed to

1. Go through a .txt file that contains a list of IPs
2. Curl each IP using a site https://ipinfo.io/ for a modified curl output

```sh
#!/bin/bash  
input="/mnt/d/Docs/BR Resources/iplist.txt"  
while IFS= read -r line  
do   
 curl https://ipinfo.io/$line  
done < "$input"
```

The expected output for each IP in the loop is :

> {   "ip": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
> "hostname": "c0241.brsol.com",
> "city": "Ashburn",
> "region": "Virginia",
> "country": "US",
> "loc": "xx.xxxx,xx.xxxx",
> "org": "BR, Inc.",
> "postal": "xxxxx",
> "timezone": "America/New_York",
> "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth" }

However, what I get as the output is this error :

> curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Example excerpt of iplist.txt

```
36.13.6.167
252.125.137.71
204.50.68.40
136.122.209.112
203.47.25.30
223.96.93.56
64.137.82.169
11.183.223.40
199.169.87.25
119.198.39.119
```

The issue seems to be that the **value of $line is not being passed alongside the rest of the curl command**.

How can I fix this to get the modified Curl output for each IP in this .txt file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `iplist.txt`?

Comment: Run this loop with echo first: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "https://ipinfo.io/$line"; done < "$input"`

Comment: @tshiono Hi, I updated the Q with an example list.

Comment: @Ivan Hi, that gives the whole command as the output. Like this : "https://ipinfo.io/36.13.6.167" ( https:// should come in front of this but StackOverFlow seems to ignore that part when it's before an IP address)

Comment: @Sandun Just tested your code and seems to work as-is. Bash version 5.0.17(1)-release.

Comment: dos2unix issue?

Comment: Is either the script or iplist.txt file in DOS/Windows format (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings))? If that's not the problem, try putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script will make it print what's happening as it runs, which can help figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Bayou I have the exact same Bash version. However I am running this code in the Ubuntu Shell in my Win 10 machine.

Comment: Change the shebang to `#! /bin/bash -x` to see more details about the commands being executed. It will most likely be a windows problem :-)

Comment: Try to wrap data into array to remove all nonprintable junk then use arayvar in curl, like this: `while IFS= read -r line; do ip=($line); curl "https://ipinfo.io/$ip"; done < "$input"`

Comment: @Bayou I added the -x to the shebang and this is the line I got for the curl:     curl $'https://ipinfo.io/36.13.6.167\r/'

Comment: @Sandun That `\r` indicates there's a (normally invisible) carriage return character at the end of the URL, probably because the ipinfo.txt file is in DOS/Windows format. If you have the `dos2unix` command, it'll convert the file to unix format. You could also use `while IFS=$'\r' read ...` to get `read` to strip the carriage return for you. The [question I linked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) has lots more details and options.

Comment: @Ivan I tried that, same error.

Comment: @Sandun or like this: `while read line; do ip=($line); curl "https://ipinfo.io/$ip"; done < "$input"`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you! Your last suggestion did the trick. Stripping the \r made it work. Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Sandun It's probably better to have all the options for dealing for DOS/Windows files in one place, so I added it as an answer under that other question and I'll mark this as a duplicate so everyone that finds your Q will be directed there.

Answer (score 1):

I did below steps on my windows machine which generated the output:
Converted the file to `dos2unix.exe ./test.sh`

test.sh:

```
# !/usr/bin/bash
input="iplist.txt"  
while IFS= read -r line  
do   
 curl https://ipinfo.io/$line  
done < "$input"
```

Ouput recieved:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   300  100   300    0     0    300      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   532
{
  "ip": "36.13.6.167",
  "hostname": "kd036013006167.ppp-bb.dion.ne.jp",
  "city": "Saitama",
  "region": "Saitama",
  "country": "JP",
  "loc": "35.9081,139.6566",
  "org": "AS2516 KDDI CORPORATION",
  "postal": "330-0853",
  "timezone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
```

bash version : GNU bash, version 4.3.42(4)-release

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on the second line? Converted the file to dos2unix.exe ./test.sh ? Does that mean I have to install something called dos2unix in my Ubuntu Shell (inside the Windows machine) ?

Comment: @Sundun I saw that your shell script was in the DOS format (\r / Carriage return CRLF) and not unix format.May be you used an editor like notepad++ which made the file in  dos format, so i converted it to a unix file by the operation dos2unix. This file then would work properly on unix .Dos format is: CRLF (each line ends with CR then LF), Unix format is : LF only (each line ends with an LF char). You can install this in ubuntu using : `sudo apt-get install dos2unix `